# chain/dependency of some rules by wildcards

Tags: snakemake

I have a particular use case for which I have not found the solution in the Snakemake documentation.

Let's say in a given pipeline I have a portion with 3 rules a, b and c which will run for N samples.

Those rules handle large amount of data and for reasons of local storage limits I do not want those rules to execute at the same time. For instance rule a produces the large amount of data then rule c compresses and export the results.

So what I am looking for is a way to chain those 3 rules for 1 sample/wildcard, and only then execute those 3 rules for the next sample. All of this to make sure the local space is available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So building on [Dmitry Kuzminov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62545073/7272135), the following can work (both with numbers as samples and strings).

The execution order will be a3 > b3 > a1 > b1 > a2 > b2.
I used a different sample order to show it can be made different from the sample list.

```
samples = [1, 2, 3]
sample_order = [3, 1, 2]

def get_previous(wildcards):
  if wildcards.sample != sample_order[0]: # if different from a3 in this case
    previous_sample = sample_order[sample_order.index(wildcards.sample) - 1]
    return f'b_out_{previous_sample}'
  else: # if is the first sample in the order i.e. a3
    return #here put dummy file always present e.g. the file containing those rules or the Snakemake

rule all:
  expand("b_out_{S}", S=sample)

rule a:
  input:
    "a_in_{sample}",
    get_previous
  output:
    "a_out_{sample}"

rule b:
  input:
    "a_out_{sample}"
  output:
    "b_out_{sample}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is problem that Snakemake still has no solution for. However you may have a workaround.

```
rule all:
    input: expand("a{sample}", sample=[1, 2, 3])

rule a:
    input: "b{sample}"
    output: "a{sample}"

rule b:
    input: "c{sample}"
    output: "b{sample}"

rule c:
    input: 
        lambda wildcards: f"a{wildcards.sample-1}"
    output: "c{sample}"
```

That means that the rule `c` for sample **2** wouldn't start before the output for rule `a` for sample **1**  is ready. You need to add a pseudo output `a0` though or make the lambda more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, good idea to use the i-1 wildcard.

Comment: Did that solve the issue? That is not a wildcard, but an additional dependency within the samples.

Comment: I did not completely get the order of your rules from your example, I posted an answer which could be applicable to a lot of cases. Don't hesitate to edit.